# Relation between b and c such that  $ b^2 + c^2 + b^2 c^2$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On the equation $(a^2+1)(b^2+1)=c^2+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31891/on-the-equation-a21b21-c21)

I came across a problem: What is relation between $b$ and $c$ such that $b^2 + c^2 + b^2 c^2$ is a perfect square?

After trying few cases, I got following relations:

- $c = 2b^2$
- $c = b+1$

But it still doesn't cover all cases e.g. $(1,12),(2,21),(2,55),(3,80),(8,30)$ etc.
How do I find general relation ?

Comment: This is $(b^2+1)(c^2+1)=d^2+1$. I think it's been asked here before - I'll be back if I find it before someone else does.